# angular dynamic (json chain) variables in ctrl variable definitions

Tags: json, angularjs, controller, chaining

Do you know how to use dynamic/chained variables inside a controller variable definition?

I have created this plnkr to further outline what I am trying to achieve: http://plnkr.co/edit/xOjhf8b7ZIxVhc1Id3xo

In the NodeCtrl, I am trying to dynamically access a node from a json object and I can't find the correct syntax to write out the chain.

I have tried a number of combinations but haven't found the correct way yet:

```
  //var jsonChunk = "data." + $scope.transcendType;
    $scope.tabinventory =  data.$scope.transcendType; 
                         //data;
                         //jsonChunk; 
                         //function() { return "data." + $scope.transcendType; };
    alert($tabinventory[0].title)
  //alert($scope.tabinventory.project[0].title);
```

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

All the best,

Ben

Comment: `data` within success handler is the object represented by your JSON. It has no property `$scope` nor any property `transcendType` so very hard to figure out what you are trying to get. Also demo throws errors from undefined function `scope.getNodeByID`

Comment: Using [ ] as my "index" was what was throwing me: http://plnkr.co/edit/2oHBuJUi1FWmiugy0nrr?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging $scope.transcendType to make sure it's properly defined in that context?

Assuming it's properly defined, try data[$scope.transcendType].

Comment: stop posting personal contact info. This site is intended for help to occur here so others in future can use responses as help also

Comment: I always post results back to Stack. I like to help people live & they like it too, then everyone gets to see the result. Win-win-win!

Comment: that;s irrelevant... not proper to post contact info here, or solicit direct contact...use profile for that and use chat system if need to

Comment: So you're advocating a worse user experience just to strictly follow the rules? Consider a career in law enforcement ;)

Comment: no...you are obviously new here... nobody posts contact info....it's tacky. Just advocating playing nice in the sandbox